# Is it required to build tensorflow from source to use inception?

Tags: tensorflow

I have already asked [this question](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/534)  in their repository, but they redirected me here on stack overflow. So, is it required to build `tensorflow` from the sources to use `inception`? Or a binary install of `tensorflow` enough to use `inception`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine from the binary install.

The [tensorflow-models repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/) has  an [example notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb) with the boiler-plate code you need to get it running.

There is also [an example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html) in the tutorials on the main site.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into those. Thanks a lot.